# remove string between two character with sed

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file of this type:

```
16:00 [61]Al-Najma - Al-Rifaa [62]5.06 [63]3.55 [64]1.57 4
```

and i want remove all the strings inside square parentheses in order to obtain

```
16:00 Al-Najma - Al-Rifaa 5.06 3.55 1.57 4
```

I am trying with sed in this manner:

```
sed 's/\[.*]//g' file1 > file2
```

but i obtain

```
16:00 1.57 4
```

and with

```
sed 's/\[.[1234567890]]//g' file1 > file2
```

does not work if the string contains more than 2 digit.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your pattern allows only one character, adding a star behind the pattern widens it to all matching characters.

```
sed 's/\[.[1234567890]]*//g' file1 > file2
```

alternative:

```
sed 's/\[^\]*//g' file1 > file2
```

that means: after the starting "[" everything but the "]" is OK, and that for as many characters as there come (the "*")

for further reading on sed: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Comment: This may work for this solution but will not scale well for all types of string between two characters. The alternative?

Comment: [1234567890] can be shortened to [0-9]

Answer (score 1):

Your first regex does not work because the quantifier `*` is greedy, meaning it matches as many characters as possible. Since `.` also matches brackets, it continues to match until the last closing bracket `]` it can find.

So you basically have two options: Use a non-greedy quantifier or restrict the types of characters you can match. You have tried the second solution. I would go with using a negated character class instead:

```
sed 's/\[[^]]*\]//g'
```

I'm not sure if sed has non-greedy quantifiers, but perl does:

```
perl -lpwe 's/\[.*?\]//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Does escaping the closing ] help ?

```
sed 's/\[.*\]//g' file1 > file2
```

Comment: `\[.*\]` is greedy and will swallow up all characters between the first `[` and the last `]` including other `][`'s.

Answer (score 0):

You already got the `sed` answer, so I will add other one using `awk`:

```
awk '
  BEGIN { 
    FS = "\\[[^]]*\\]"; 
    OFS = " " 
  } 
  { 
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
      printf "%s", $i 
  } 
  END { 
    printf "\n" 
  }
' <<<"16:00 [61]Al-Najma - Al-Rifaa [62]5.06 [63]3.55 [64]1.57 4"
```

Output:

```
16:00 Al-Najma - Al-Rifaa 5.06 3.55 1.57 4
```

Answer (score 0):

#### using `awk`:

```
$ echo '16:00 [61]Al-Najma - Al-Rifaa [62]5.06 [63]3.55 [64]1.57 4' | awk -F '\[[0-9]*\]' '$1=$1'
16:00  Al-Najma - Al-Rifaa  5.06  3.55  1.57 4
```

Comment: same as my solution (didn't post) ;) btw, the two "\" could be saved.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo "16:00 [61]Al-Najma - Al-Rifaa [62]5.06 [63]3.55 [64]1.57 4" |
sed 's/\[[^]]*\]//g'
16:00 Al-Najma - Al-Rifaa 5.06 3.55 1.57 4
```